# с++ Как приостановить выполнение программы?

Tags: c++

как приостановить выполнение программы? 
пишу тетрис с++ sfml Visual Studio 
нужно в определенной точке цикла остановить выполнение программы на некоторое время (каждый раз будет разное время)

Answer (score -4):

Есть функция `sleep`. Она находится в `Windows.h`. Пример использования:

```
Sleep(2000);
```

В скобках указываем время в миллисекундах. Вместо числа можно использовать переменную.